# How to solve $x'(t)=\sin(tx(t))$ with $x(0)=\zeta$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I don‘t know how to solve this first order ODE:

> How to solve $x'(t)=\sin(tx(t))$ with $x(0)=\zeta$

Maybe it's somehow possible to transform this into a linear ODE, but I can‘t see how. At least I think I need to solve it to proof:

a) The initial value problem has for every $\zeta \in \mathbb{R}$ a unique maximal solution.

b) For every $\zeta \in \mathbb{R}$ is the solution an even function.

I guess a) is a conclution of the global version of Picard-Lindelöff, but it seems like I need an explicit solution for part b.

Comment: You don't need an explicit solution for b). Only uniqueness of the maximal solution, which you have as you pointed out. Try thinking how you can see the "left" part of the solution, the one going from 0 to $- \infty$

Answer (score 1):

Let $z(t)=y(-t)$. Then $z(0)=\zeta$ and
$$
z'(t)=-y'(-t)=-\sin((-t)y(-t))=\sin(tz(t))
$$
So you get a second solution for the same IVP.